# How to implement recaptcha by placing script only

Tags: javascript, captcha, recaptcha

i not know much more but i know that in a application i use recaptcha and make them work by placing a javascript only.

are you know that how Recaptcha work by placing javascript only on webpage.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        Recaptcha.create("6Ld70wQAAAAAAKqf1MVuaDXWluR2MQblCQGgiKlf",
    "recaptcha",
    {
        theme: "red",
        callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
    }
  );
    </script>enter code here`

i use this script but not found that's work. how i can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need your own API key**, which can be created [here](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create).

***Without a valid API key, it will not work.***